# How to integrate functions in n dimensional space?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have a question about an example of functions in Sobolev space. But I think you can give a hint without knowing the Sobolev space because I just want to know how to integrate a function with n-dimensional domain.

Question : If $u(x)=|x|^{-\alpha}$, $x \in U=$ the open punctured unit ball in $\bf{R}^n$, then for which values of $\alpha >0, n, p$ does $u$ belong to $W^{1,p}(U)$?

Clearly, $u$ is locally summable. So I want to show that $||u||_p+\sum \int_U|u_{x_i}|^pdx$ is finite.

But I don't know how to integrate a function over $U$. I tried the iterated integral but it is so cumbersome. Please give me any hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use **polar coordinates**, i.e. the fact that $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n} f(x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty r^{n-1} \int_{S^{n-1}} f(r\xi) \, dS(\xi) \, dr$, where $dS$ is the surface measure of the unit sphere. There are also different formulations of this formula which may or may not be easier for your (if you do not like/know the surface measure).