# for which values of $p$ integral $\int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{|x|^p}$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, containing the origin. My question is as in subject: for which values of $p\in\mathbb{R}$ the integral $\int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{|x|^p}$ exists? It's easy to find the answer for $n=1$ and then also for $n=2$ and $n=3$, using polar and spherical coordinates respectively, and it seems that the answer should be $p<n$. However, I'm not sure how to prove this for $n>3$.

Note that I found some similar questions already posted, in particular [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151979/how-to-integrate-functions-in-n-dimensional-space), but I don't fully understand the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the integrand has a singularity only at the origin, we might as well assume that $\Omega = B(0,\varepsilon)$. Assuming that $n \geq 2$ and using (generalized) [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates), the integral can be written as

$$ \int_{0}^1 \int_0^{2\pi} \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi} \dots \int_0^{\pi}}_{n-2 \text{ integrals}} \frac{1}{r^p} r^{n-1} \sin^{n-2}(\phi_1)\sin^{n-3}(\phi_2) \dots \sin(\phi_{n-2}) \, dr \, d\phi_1 \dots d\phi_{n-1} = \\
\left( \int_0^1 r^{n-1-p} \, dr \right) \left( \int_0^{2\pi} \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi} \dots \int_0^{\pi}}_{n-2 \text{ integrals}} \sin^{n-2}(\phi_1)\sin^{n-3}(\phi_2) \dots \sin(\phi_{n-2}) \, d\phi_1 \dots d\phi_{n-1} \right). $$

Since the second integral converges, we are left with discussing the convergence of

$$ \int_0^1 r^{n-1-p} \, dr $$

which is a one-dimensional problem. This integral converges if and only if $n - 1 - p > -1$ or $n > p$.

Comment: Nice, thanks for answering.  You've probably meant $\sin^{n-3}(\phi_{2})$ instead of $\sin^{n-1}(\phi_{2})$ above, right?

Comment: @Crni Yep, I've corrected it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but should be corrected on the right side of the equation too.

Comment: @Crni: Corrected.